# How to use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinary method?

Tags: development, client-object-model, file

I want to save a file from document library to local drive. I am using the Client Object model approach model in development. The following is the code that I use:

```
processSheet.SaveBinary(FileSaveBinaryInformation);
```

But I am not able to understand what is to be passed as a parameter of the type

> FileSaveBinaryInformation

Note: processSheet is the type of

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File

Please guide.

Answer (score 3):

Save document library file to local file system using CSOM.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{

     var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
     clientContext.Load(list);
     clientContext.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


     var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
     var filePath = "C:/";
     var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);
     var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath,(string)listItem.File.Name);
     using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
     {                  
          fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered here. used Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass stream of Bytes or Byte array which you are supposed to save to the file.

Comment: Can you please give me an example link or a code block?

Comment: Sure please let me know what kind of data you are storing back to file? is it some string or file data  and by client object you mean JS n not C# right ?

Comment: Please give us example of Word file with content in it